# Is it possible to have an override method call its abstract virtual method?

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual, abstract

My goal is to have the Abstract class update on its own once `Consume` is called on one of the derived classes.

Imagine this:

```
public interface IConsumable 
{
    void Consume();
}

public abstract class AbstractConsumable : IConsumable
{
    private bool _consumed = false;

    public virtual void Consume()
    {
        _consumed = true;
    }
}

public class HealthyConsumable: AbstractConsumable
{
    public override void Consume()
    {
        // Do something healthy and ...
        base.Consume(); // Would like to avoid this...
    }
}

public class PoisonousConsumable: AbstractConsumable
{
    public override void Consume()
    {
        // Do something poisonous and ...
        base.Consume(); // Would like to avoid this...
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve here is not having to call `base.Consume()` on the `override` methods, but still have the abstract class set `_consumed` once the derived classes call their `Consume()` methods.

Comment: Rather than saying that you think your question is obvious, and that you don't actually need to ask a question, you should actually ask a question anyway, and explain what you're actually trying to do.  It doesn't end well trying to get people to guess what you actually want.

Comment: I have updated the question, so its a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make Consume none virtual and within it you called another protected virtual (or abstract method) that can contain code that be change by sub classes. Consumers of your class can only call the public Consume method but this will intern call the sub class implementation specific code

```
public interface IConsumable 
{
    void Consume();
}

public abstract class AbstractConsumable : IConsumable
{
    private bool _consumed = false;

    public void Consume()
    {
        _consumed = true;
        InternalConsumerBehaviour();
    }

    protected virtual void InternalConsumeBehaviour()
    {
         //default do nothing could potentially mark this method abstract rather than virtual its up to you
    }
}

public class HealthyConsumable: AbstractConsumable
{
    protected override void InternalConsumeBehaviour()
    {
        // Do something healthy and ...
    }
}

public class PoisonousConsumable: AbstractConsumable
{
    protected override void InternalConsumeBehaviour()
    {
        // Do something poisonous and ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you too! More or less the same answer as @d219 provided. Not sure who to mark as answer now :P

Comment: @d219's answer made consume effects public meaning someone could call it without calling consume and so _consumed would never be set. Its minor and I'm just pointing it out for your sake, I don't mind which answer you want to accept

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you're asking right you could do something like this:

```
public interface IConsumable 
{
    void Consume();
}

public abstract class AbstractConsumable : IConsumable
{
    private bool _consumed = false;

    public abstract void ConsumeEffects();

    public void Consume()
    {
        this.ConsumeEffects();
        _consumed = true;
    }
}

public class HealthyConsumable: AbstractConsumable
{
    public override void ConsumeEffects()
    {
        // Do something healthy and ...
        // Consume will get called in the base
    }
}

public class PoisonousConsumable: AbstractConsumable
{
    public override void ConsumeEffects()
    {
        // Do something poisonous and ...
        // Consume will get called in the base
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Pretty obvious solution once I see it. Thank you!